# Can't access TimePicker (Silverlight 4) Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0, timepicker

I use Visual Studio 2010, and I recently installed Silverlight 4 Toolkit. However I still can't access TimePicker. System.Windows.Control is in the Solution Reference, and it also doesn't show the new Silverlight controls. In the VS 2010 installation directory, I can see Silverlight 4 (and 3). Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Are you referencing `System.Windows.Controls.Input`?  Also, if your not already, toolkit can be installed with [nuget](http://nuget.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Darek, Thanks for the reply. I updated VS 2010 to its new service pack; I also tried installing Silverlight 4. In both cases I can't add System.Windows.Controls.Input to the references as it doesn't exist...

Comment: The dll that needs to be referenced is: System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit.dll
Add the following namespace: xmlns:toolkitInput="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit"
toolkitInput:TimePicker should be now available to you